# Sending array via JavaScript to nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 2 working scripts which I am trying use in conjunction with each other first is my JavaScript:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function textareaToArray(t){
        return t.value.split(/[\n\r]+/);
    }
    function showArray(msg){
        for(i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
            // something per item
            alert(msg[i]);
        }
        // the old code
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = msg.join("&#013;");
    }
</script>
```

and then I have a nodejs script which accepts postdata

```
http://localhost.com/?name=Data
```

basically where it says

```
alert(msg[i]);
```

in my JavaScript I would like to postdata to

localhost.com/?name= msg[i]  << this is an example of what I want to do

```
  var url = require('url');
  var http = require('http');
  var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  var queryData = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});

  if (queryData.name) {
    // user told us their name in the GET request, ex: http://host:8000/?name=Tom
    var basevalue = queryData.name;
    var value = basevalue.split (":");
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    console.log(value[0]);
    exec ("casperjs test.js " + value[0] + " " + value[1] + '\n',function(err, stdout, stderr) {

        response.end('data sent');

    });

  } else {
    response.end("Contact Admin - Not Working\n");
  }
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

my JavaScript so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function textareaToArray(t){
        return t.value.split(/[\n\r]+/);
    }
    function showArray(msg){
        for(i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
            // something per item
            var data = {}; //your own data
    $.post("https://new-c9-ashg1990.c9.io" + "?" + $.param({name: msg[i]}), data);
            alert(msg[i]);
        }
        // the old code
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = msg.join("&#013;");
    }
  </script>
```

How can I fix my code so it shows my response from node.js?

Comment: what do you mean by "postdata"? Are you trying to do an http post request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you use jQuery in your project.

So jQuery provides good method to do that things **$.param**

This is official example:

```
var myObject = {
  a: {
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
    three: 3
  },
  b: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
};
$.param(myObject);
// result is "a%5Bone%5D=1&a%5Btwo%5D=2&a%5Bthree%5D=3&b%5B%5D=1&b%5B%5D=2&b%5B%5D=3"
```

In your case you have

```
function send(message){
   var message = message || "";
   var url = "SOME_URL";
   $.ajax({
     url: url,
     method: "GET",
     data: { name: message },
     success: function(res){
       alert(res);
     },
     error: function(e){
       alert(e);
     }
   });
}
send("some text or message");
```

Comment: could you show me an example that corrosponds with my java script above please i am new to all this if you can show me how to send msg[i] as postdata

Comment: @user3318717 when you say postdata you mean post request or get request with post data?

Comment: i have a nodejs server wich accepts postdata http://localhost:8328/?name= the data i need is msg[i] i want javascript to send msg[i] to the node script so if msg[i] = foo the nodejs would look like http://localhost:8328/?name=foo

Comment: awsome i got it sending data :) how can i echo the response from that script

Comment: @user3318717 i edited see, you can use response argument

Comment: unfortuantly that would not work for me i need to get the actual string that the nodejs script sends back

Comment: can you write what inside response object, and what server returns

Comment: i will add the nodejs script above

Comment: okay thats a bit confusing heres what i have so far check my edit out

Comment: check my above javascript

Comment: @user3318717 add success function after data!

Comment: will this echo the data back that node.js produces?

Comment: Depends on what you write inside your callback!

Comment: you do not understand what i mean node.js produces 3 types of echo response either notworking or valid or invalid depending on the data i send to it so i ask again how do i get java scrit to grab what node.js produces take a look at my script https://new-c9-ashg1990.c9.io/ i want javascript to be able to grab the string nodejs returns